# Automapper include all properties from parent class

Tags: c#, automapper

I've the following code:

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

namespace AutoMapperPlayground
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var derived = new Derived {
                Title = "a",
                Base = new Base {
                    Id = 1,
                    Test = "b"
                }
            };


            Mapper.CreateMap<Derived, DerivedDTO>();
            

            var derivedDTO = Mapper.Map<DerivedDTO>(derived);
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", derivedDTO.Test, derivedDTO.Id, derivedDTO.Title);         
            
        }
    }

    public class Base
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Test {get; set; }
    }

    public class Derived
    {
        
        public Base Base {get; set; }
        public string Title {get; set; }

    }

    public class BaseDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Test {get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedDTO : BaseDTO
    {
        public string Title {get; set; } 
    }
}
```

The output is ,0,a.
Would it be possible to have `id` and `title` properties populated from `Base`?

[Sample .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gMPfk3)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the context is, but your parallel data structures don't match. There's no way for it to infer a mapping from a composition pattern to an inheritance pattern. You could specify a custom mapping function. However, you should restructure your code because you are using a misleading naming convention

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flattening](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html) is one of the core concepts of AutoMapper, and is done by convention; your DTO property names need to be prefixed with the property name of the composed object in your source type:

```
public class DerivedDTO
{
    public int BaseId { get; set; }
    public string BaseTest { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } 
}
```

However, if you want to retain your existing structure (`DerivedDTO` inheriting from `BaseDTO`), you would need to define those mappings manually:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Derived, DerivedDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Base.Id)),
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Test, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Base.Test));
```

Or you could create a mapping from `Base` to `DerivedDTO`, and include that in your `Derived` mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Base, DerivedDTO>(); // Map Id and Test

Mapper.CreateMap<Derived, DerivedDTO>() // Map Title
    .IncludeMembers(src => src.Base); // Reuse above mapping to include Base Id and Test
```